# Solr Indexing multiple json objects

Tags: solr

I am trying to learn solr but some of the technicalities are confusing me. 
I have a large document that are basically structured like this:

```
url -> {Some giant json object}
url -> {another giant json object}
...
url -> {another giant json object}
```

and there are close to 30,000 of them. 
I want to index them to solr. So I created a schema.xml that has every possible field and whether it is indexed, multivalued etc etc.

I am wondering what is the general structure of what to do next. I understand that I have to index the file, but do I use a curl command for each line separately? 
Just looking for a higher level understanding of things because the online sources are a little confusing to me.

Thank you!

EDIT--
Are terminal commands the fastest way of indexing these particular type of file? I updated the example the show how the json file looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Curl request

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update/json/docs'
'?split=/exams'
'&f=first:/first'
'&f=last:/last'
'&f=grade:/grade'
'&f=subject:/exams/subject'
'&f=test:/exams/test'
'&f=marks:/exams/marks'
 -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
```

This will index data as

```
{
  "first": "John",
  "last": "Doe",
  "grade": 8,
  "exams": [
      {
        "subject": "Maths",
        "test"   : "term1",
        "marks":90},
        {
         "subject": "Biology",
         "test"   : "term1",
         "marks":86}
      ]
}'
```

To know more follow this link -

https://lucidworks.com/blog/2014/08/12/indexing-custom-json-data/